# How to show input as html?

Tags: node.js, discord, ejs

Hello I was making a website in which I want user to see their input in preview sections.
so if someone type: `<h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>` then below preview section should show HELLO WORLD! as heading 1 in ejs.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label><i class="fad fa-texts"></i> Long Description<span style="color: rgb(175, 22, 22)">*</span>
                <p class="text-muted">(Html supported but markdown not supported)</p>
                </label>
                  <textarea name="longDesc" onkeypress="dis()" id="longDesc" class="form-control" minlength="300" required="required" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></textarea>
                  <textarea name="liveDesc" id="liveDesc" class="form-control" minlength="300" required="required" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
```

```
<script>
  function dis (){


    var botdesc = document.getElementById("longdesc");
  var visualizer = document.getElementById("livedesc");
  botdesc.addEventListener("keyup",async (e) => {
   const dirtyhtml = marked(botdesc.value.replaceAll(/&gt;+/g, ">").replaceAll(/&lt;+/g, "<"));
   const noicehtml = sanitizeHtml(dirtyhtml, {
     allowedTags: sanitizeHtml.defaults.allowedTags.concat(['discord-message','discord-messages', 'img','iframe', 'style', 'h1', 'h2', 'link', 'mark', 'svg', 'span']),
     allowVulnerableTags: true,
     allowedAttributes: {
      '*': ["*"]
     }
    });
    visualizer.innerHTML = noicehtml;
  });

}
```

example below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udgxb.jpg

Comment: Suggestions for what? Is there a problem? Or are you asking for opinions (which will get your question closed). What is your question?

Comment: sorry written it by mistake

Comment: @Rob bro please help if you can

Comment: @ATGaming I really tried to fully explain in the last answer, hope I hit the spot c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript, **you can get a value from input or textarea and then push it in any element as HTML child nodes**

For example, you have this HTML:

```
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="onChange()"></textarea>

<div id="htmlView"></div>
```

In this example, we are going to get value from the textarea and then **push HTML nodes in the htmlView div**

For this, we can write a function:

```
function onChange() {
  // get value
  const text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  // set plain text as HTML nodes
  document.getElementById("htmlView").innerHTML = text;
}
```

And, as you can see, it works

[image: An image of result]

```js
function onChange() {
  const text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("htmlView").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="onChange()"></textarea>

<div id="htmlView"></div>
```